# Update field so that parameter in SQL has 16 character length

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am writing a stored procedure that will dummy some credit card data (please note that this is not live!) It is for internal purposes only. This sp runs, but it is only printing out a subset of 10 character (numeric) lengths and not 16. Does anyone have any insight?

Here is my SProc:

```
DECLARE @RESULT int

DECLARE @cc as varchar(50) = (SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))

UPDATE trans

SET trans_CCNUM =(SELECT stuff(@cc,1,LEN(@cc)-4,REPLICATE('x', LEN(@cc)-5)))

where LEN(trans_ccNum) = 16;

PRINT @RESULT
```

Here are the results

dateCreated             trans_CCNUM

---

2014-09-11 16:55:13.800 xxxx9328

Comment: I am terrified at this question. It sounds as if you are storing credit card data in your live environment in clear text. Have you not heard? Storing credit card data like that is criminal. Do yourself and your company a favor and get the real data encrypted. You might look into PCI compliance. Clear text credit card numbers is light years away from where you need to be to protect your data.

Comment: Please read my above comment. I explained this isnt in a live app nor will it be @SeanLange

Comment: You said it isn't live. You never said your live environment doesn't store credit card data. So if it isn't for anything what is the point?

Comment: so when we create development environments we can mask our data ( our application actually does encrypt credit card information but this is for our internal testing purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your example above, **@cc** is only going to be 9 or 10 characters long...

```
DECLARE @cc as varchar(50) = 
    (SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))

    SELECT @cc,len(@cc)

    select stuff(@cc,1,LEN(@cc)-4,REPLICATE('x', LEN(@cc)-5))
```

That is why you are only seeing 9/10 characters

Try changing the **INT** to **BIGINT** and you should be OK

Comment: Thanks @Sparky. Worked great.